# Возможно ли получить список товаров через GET или иным способом?

Tags: virtuemart, joomla

Здравствуйте.

Пишу курсовой проект на delphi, требуется получить список товаров с магазина.

Имеется ли функция у этого компонента получить список, сделав запрос get, получив в ответ либо все товары магазина, либо конкретный товар, который был запрошен?

В документации к VirtueMart есть что-то про get, но я не нашел там примеров http://docs.virtuemart.net/api-vm2/d6/df4/class_vm_config.html#a05141a3b94d1ebb33f0ae80fcbf38dd7

Поиск в Интернете ничего подобного не дал.
Или мне стоит искать данной возможности в другом компоненте?
Дело в том, что с web технологиями раньше не имел дело, вот и обращаюсь к вам.

VirtueMart 3.0.6.2, Joomla! 3.4.0

Answer (score 1):

в Joomla чтоб получить POST или GET передаваемые данные можно использовать

```
$get = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get;
$bla = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get->getString('bla');
$post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post;
$bla = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getString('bla')->get;
$bla = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getString('bla');
$bla = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('bla', 'string or int or bool or float');
```